# How to create JWT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, token, json-web-token

I am new to JWT, I am trying to create a simple JWT in javascript, send it to a controller (using web-api), check it in sql database.
 when I googled the net I found a examples like:
//HEAD

```
  {"typ":"JWT",
          "alg":"HS256"}
```

//claims

```
{
  "Id": 445566,
  "name": "Meme Jhon",
  "password": "ticktack"
}
```

//and signature.

I want to create in Javascript my First JWT but i feel something is missing.. what is the full structure? it's not seem logical to start only with the head (like example above..)I need a full example or explaination or a link to a full example. 
Thank you

Comment: When you say JavaScript do you mean server-side in node.js?

Comment: I mean plain javascript.

Comment: node.js - that's still plain JavaScript, you mean on the client side.

Comment: yes, on the client side, I just want to write JWT , must I use node.js ? yes on the client side

Comment: See the core concept of JWT generation being done server-side below..otherwise _signing_ becomes pointless.

Comment: @EdSF still useful to create JWT in es6 import syntax, which these node libs don't support

Comment: @Nikos unsure what you mean? Client side? Bottom line is client side is accessible. Any `keys` used in `signing` is therefore accessible (not a secret) and makes it pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [JWT spec](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html) to get a full understanding.

To summarize, at the end of the day, it's a way to send data (claims) between 2 parties in a *secure* fashion:

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties.

The structure looks like this (taken straight out of the spec):

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLA0KICJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
.
eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFt
cGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
.
dBjftJeZ4CVP-mB92K27uhbUJU1p1r_wW1gFWFOEjXk
```

- 3 base64url encoded segments separated by a dot (`.`)

  - header
  - claim/payload
  - signature

The core concept of server-side generation has to do with *signing* - though if you don't want to sign, therefore "unsecured JWT" (refer to spec), then I guess you can do everything client-side.

Implementation details vary - e.g. the above can be the payload of some HTTP request, auth schemes (see link in @M.M. answer for such), etc.

[Google Wallet](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/web/api-reference#masked-wallet-request-jwt) is an example of an *implementation* of the spec.

Refer to the link provided above by @M.M. for libraries

Comment: I need to build a token in JS and send it to my c# file. I need a FULL exampke not pieces , can you help? thanks :-)

Comment: @Damkulul - Sorry, not really. I've never/haven't considered unsecure JWT (no signature, etc) so building/generating in client side Javascript isn't something I've done. For tinkering/experimental purposes - you'll need to base64url encode JSON for the necessary segments. That should get you going to **try** something. Hth.

Comment: if the user needs to send a JWT  to the server (to login) and the info is send to the server by $.AJAX (from JavaScript section in HTML page) than I need to create the JWT in javascript. please let me know if I am missing something .. thanks

Comment: @Damkulul see the linked implementation sample in [M.M. answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262872/304683). [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543) is another (just get past some of the terminology used as you'll see in the comments). Hth.